# Spotfire - Sum only max value

Tags: sum, max, spotfire

in Spotfire i need to sum only the max value of every category.
For example:

| Category | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |

```
Sum(Max([Value] over ([Category])))
```

In this case I expect it to return to me as a result 2+4=6 but give me 14 as if it inserts the calculated max in each row of the category and then adds everything.

How can i do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
Sum(CASE WHEN Rank([Value],"desc",[Category],"ties.method=first")=1 then [Value] end)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for a calculated column: all the rows filled with the same value

```
Sum(If([Value]=Max([Value]) over ([Category]),[Value],0))
```

It would not work for a dynamic item (I think that it does not like expressions with OVER)

Comment: but if the maximum value is repeated it counts it n times, where n is the number of copies. For now I have solved it like this:

Sum(Max[Value]over ([Categoty])/Count([Value])over ([Category]))

Comment: True, but I used the sample provided, please in the future add samples that reflect a realistic situation.

Comment: Sorry you're right, I modified the question by including this case to make it more complete. Thanks all the same for the answer